# SignalR javascript hub method not firing in IE after a period of inactivity

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I have a SignalR (v0.5.2) Hub sending a message to a JavaScript client.

c#

```
public Task SendData(ClassName classData){
    return Clients["groupid"].renderData(classData);
}
```

javascript

```
var _client = $.connection.myHub;
_client.renderData = function(data){
    /* do stuff */
};

$.connection.hub.start({ transport:activeTransport }, function(){ });
```

All works fine except that after a period of inactivity in IE9, the JavaScript method fails to run.

I have looked at the Response Body of the `/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame` network log within IE9 developer tools and can see that I am receiving the message:

```
<script>r(c, {"MessageId":"54","Messages":[{"Hub":"myHub","Method":"renderData","Args":[....]]}],"Disconnect":false,"TimedOut":false,"TransportData":{"Groups":["LiveBid.999"]}});</script>
<div>{"MessageId":"54","Messages":[{"Hub":"myHub","Method":"renderData","Args":[....]]}],"Disconnect":false,"TimedOut":false,"TransportData":{"Groups":["LiveBid.999"]}}</div>
```

Yet the JavaScript method never fires?

Comment: This doesn't, by any chance, tend to happen in exact 10-minute intervals does it? I have a similar issue: I have a server-side clock that's displayed on the client, and it freezes every 10 minutes (because changes stop getting received). The time that it freezes at is different for different users, but for the same user, it always freezes at the same (Minute % 10):(Second).

Comment: @Nathan yeah it seems to be every 10 seconds.

Comment: @Nathan see my answer below. can you let me know if you have a Modernizr file in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time spent debugging this, it turns out that it is the version of my Modernizr file which is causing the problem.

I am not massively familiar with how the inners of Modernizer work, however I have created a custom version of the file that only has css/html5 elements features, and this currently seems to work with SignalR and foreverFrame.

Comment: I doubt this will solve my issue: I've never used Modernizr, so it won't be in my project. Be aware, though, that for me, this bug is really difficult to pin down. It only appears for certain combinations of [client, server, build revision], and only in IE. I hope your issue does not come back for you. :)